# Pricebook and PricebookEntries with different currencies

Tags: quote, pricebook, quotelineitem, pricebookentry

Can Pricebook and its PricebookEntries have different currencies? So, if I create a Pricebook with currency USD and its PricebookEntries with multiple currency like USD, GBP, AUD, etc., is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One `Pricebook` can have multiple `Pricebookentries` for the same `Product2`.

### Example

**Pricebook2:** `MyCustomPricebook`

**Product2:** `MySKU`

**PricebookEntries**

```
MyCustomPricebookId MySKUId USD 10.00
MyCustomPricebookId MySKUId EUR  9.50
MyCustomPricebookId MySKUId GBP  8.85
```

`PricebookEntry` is a junction record between `Pricebook2` and `Product2`; each instance given the same parents is for a different currency.  The typical use case is to offer a SKU in different markets where the business is selling across borders and customers prefer to use their local currency.

Comment: I've activated multi currency in the setup page and added a couple currencies, but they don't show up in the Price book entry dropdown. Why is that?

Comment: @ChrisSH - you should ask this as a different question on this site

Answer (score 1):

Price books do not have a currency (there is no CurrencyIsoCode field). Salesforce includes special behavior that allows only one product per currency per price book. In other words, a price book entry has a *unique composite key constraint*. You can add the same product to a price book multiple times, one for each currency you'd like to sell the product in. You cannot add the same product for the same currency more than once in a price book.